# Why is my partial screen shot blurry in swift?

Tags: swift

This is my code to take a partial screen shot in my app! The screenshot size is exactly how I want it, but when I pull it up in the Camera Roll the image looks out of focus and not the quality I want.  What is wrong with the code I have written?

```
    @IBAction func screenShotButton(sender: Any Object) {
       let top: CGFloat = 196
       let bottom: CGFloat = 197
       let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - top - bottom)
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -top)
    view.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapshot, nil, nil, nil)
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of the blurry screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and pass 0 as the scale.

Per the documentation of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`:

> This function is equivalent to calling the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function with the opaque parameter set to NO and a scale factor of 1.0.

The following describes the scale factor parameter of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`:

> The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

In other words, on a retina device such as an iPhone 6 the native scale factor is 2, or 3 on an iPhone 6 Plus.  Passing 0 as the scale parameter will select the correct scale factor for the current device.

Comment: Why won't it let me change my opaque parameter to "NO"? It keeps saying there is an error

Comment: NO is false in Swift.

Comment: @BrandonPriest Please accept this answer if you found it helpful.  Thanks!